# mysql not working , it is not starting

Tags: mysql, xampp

here is a bit of the error log .

```
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665244 and 1665244   in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 15857945 in the ib_logfiles!
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 15857945
160422 10:45:00 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 2 !!!
160422 10:45:00 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160422 10:45:00 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
160422 10:45:00 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
160422 10:45:00 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
```

plz somebody help , i have one important database ,whose backup i have not made , i posted this question earlier ,but didnt got the answer ...this started when i was trying to access phpmyadmin , from then on mysql is not starting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [myql in xampp stops immediately after starting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777161/myql-in-xampp-stops-immediately-after-starting)

Comment: yes that is my question only , but i not getting any answers ...what do i do :(

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential ways out of it.

For the following:

```
Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
```

You can use mysqlcheck to repair it, if it is a MyISAM DB. Else try the InnoDB force recovery option if it is InnoDB database. You can start your DB with InnoDB force recovery and take a DB dump from it, to restore it on a fresh MySQL install.

In future, try enabling innodb_file_per_table option.

Now, second option. Even though the first one looks most likely.

```
The log sequence numbers 1665244 and 1665244   in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 15857945 in the ib_logfiles!
```

If the first method doesnt work, give this a try. It looks like the ib_logfiles are corrupt, I faced this issue before and used the following steps to get my DB up and working:

1. Take a full backup of your mysql datadir in another directory.
2. Make sure mysql service is stopped.
3. remove the ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile2
4. Start the MySQL service

Hope it helps

Comment: after i deleted log data and two other log files it say some operating syste, error

Comment: i didn't get your first point ? i think i have tried innodb_force_recovery =1 or 2 , and it saying that it cant recover

Comment: i tried it again and its saying innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
.
160422 11:18:56 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
160422 11:18:56 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

Comment: Please try the new answer I have added.

Comment: thanks bro ,but i uninstalled xampp and reinstalled it , i had saved the data  folder of prev xampp , i want  a particular database , i have its folder in the data folder of prev xampp ,named 'mydbrun' . i pasted this folder in data folder of new installation .but when i see phpmyadmin only the database name and table names are there ,but no content or even structure of those tables ...can you plz help me with this ? can i recover database like this ?

Comment: You either place a complete mysql dir at new location to achieve something like this, or restore from the DB dump taken from the previous xampp installation. Placing the files for one DB is going to do you no good.

Answer (score 0):

Rishav, innodb_force_recovery doesn't recover anything. It is a mode you start your mysql with. Once it starts, you should be able to take a dump. Following should be the steps:

Steps to get it back up.

```
1. Stop mysqld.
2. Backup /var/lib/mysql/ib*
3. Add the following line into /etc/my.cnf
innodb_force_recovery = 4
4. Restart mysqld.
5. Dump your DB using mysqldump to a dump.sql file.
6. Drop all databases which need recovery.
7. Stop mysqld.
8. Remove /var/lib/mysql/ib*
9. Comment out innodb_force_recovery in /etc/my.cnf
10. Restart mysqld. Look at mysql error log. By default it should be /var/lib/mysql/server/hostname.com.err to see how it creates new ib* files. (Although, I recommend a fresh setup here)
11. Restore databases from the dump:mysql < dump.sql
```